# Composable doesn't recompose although LiveData changes

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-jetpack-compose

I simply want to add a Node to a List when the user clicks a button and display it in a composable LazyColumn.

Here is how I thought it would work:
VieModel:

```
    private val _nodeList: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Node>> = MutableLiveData()
    val nodeList: LiveData<MutableList<Node>> = _nodeList

    fun onNodeListChange(newNode: Node){
        _nodeList.value?.add(newNode)
}
```

and in my Composable I try to observe it by calling:

```
val vm = getViewModel<MainViewModel>()
val nodeList: List<Node> by vm.nodeList.observeAsState(listOf())
```

In the onClick of the Button I call:

```
val newNode = Node(title, body)
vm.onNodeListChange(newNode)
```

The node gets added to the nodeList in the ViewModel but the Composable wont recompose.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LiveData is not changing. You are just adding a new item to the list stored within the LiveData. For a LiveData to notify it's observers, the object returned by `livedata.getValue()` must occupy a different memory space from the one supplied through `livedata.setValue()`  One quick and dirty solution would be:

`_nodeList.value = _nodeList?.value?.toMutableList()?.apply{add(newNode)}`

In Jetpack compose you probably want to use a `SnapShotStateList` for an observable list instead of a `LiveData<List<T>>`

Comment: So what would be a clean way to add an item to LiveData?

lol just found your answer on some stackoverflow question while googling for SnapShotStateList https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65039054/jetpack-compose-lazycolumnfor-not-recomposing-when-item-added

Comment: Well, maybe the cleanest solution is what I've posted above. In your case, the LiveData object will expect you to assign a whole list to it if you want your observers to be notified.

Comment: Thank you, it works.
You said "quick and dirty solution" thats why I asket if there is a clean solution to it

Comment: You are using Jetpack Compose, so a clean solution would be SnapShotStateList

Comment: Thank you, the suggestion to use SnapShotStateList was very helpful