# Compose not recomposing on state change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

I have a compose UI for bottom sheet and I want to update the bottom sheet on data change. I am passing a state to the composable but its not recomposing on data change.

```
private var title = MutableLiveData()
    private var subTitle= MutableLiveData()
```

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                MyTheme(themeColorMode = ThemeColorMode.Light) {
                    RelayInfoHalfCard(title = title.observeAsState(), subTitle = subTitle.observeAsState()) {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

my update function

```
fun updateData(title: String, subTitle: String) {
        this.title.value = title
        this.subTitle.value = subTitle
    }
```

my Compose code

```
@Composable
fun RelayInfoHalfCard(title: State<String>, subTitle:State<String>, onDismiss: () -> Unit){

        HalfCard(topPadding = 20.dp) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(start=10.dp,end=10.dp, bottom = 10.dp)
        ) {
            
            Text(
                text = title.value,
                 modifier = Modifier.padding(start=24.dp,end=24.dp,top=8.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = subTitle.value,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start=24.dp,end=24.dp,top=8.dp)
            )
            Button(text = "Got it",Modifier.
            padding(start=20.dp,end=20.dp, bottom = 28.dp,top=36.dp)
                .clickable(onClick = onDismiss))

        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why its not working?

Comment: Could you please share a code of RelayInfoHalfCard()

Comment: I have added it in my question

Comment: Is any part of the code updating title and subTitle instead of their value? Everything posted looks good, but they should be vals not vars

Comment: Try in your ``RelayInfoHalfCard`` function to replace parameters State<T> to T and pass the value of the state

Comment: Can you please update the code snippet with the proper imports?

Answer (score 0):

In Jetpack compose you probably want to use a `remember` for an observable data rather then a `LiveData`

Here is the working code snippet:-

```
    fun RelayInfoHalfCard(
        title: String,
        subTitle: String,
        onDismiss: () -> Unit
    ) {

        val title by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        val subTitle by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        Card {

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp)
            ) {

                Text(
                    text = title,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 24.dp, end = 24.dp, top = 8.dp)
                )
                Text(
                    text = subTitle,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 24.dp, end = 24.dp, top = 8.dp)
                )
                Button(
                    onClick = onDismiss, modifier = Modifier.padding(
                        start = 20.dp,
                        end = 20.dp,
                        bottom = 28.dp,
                        top = 36.dp
                    )
                ) { Text("Click me") }
            }
        }
    }

    RelayInfoHalfCard(title = title, subTitle = subTitle)
    { dismiss() }
```

The compose compiler need a `mutableStateOf` to `remember` the recomposition, it will trigger the recomposition as soon as the state of `mutableStateOf` is changed

Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68638161/composable-doesnt-recompose-although-livedata-changes) for further explanation.

Comment: You can't call `remember` outside of a composable function.

Comment: @ScottStanchfield It was a typo mistake in my editor it is under a `composable` block

Answer (score 0):

its not working because you are passing state object which is not changing.. for RelayInfoHalfCard to work you gotta pass its value because thats changing, so that RelayInfoHalfCard reads the value of state..

Recomposition only happens if the state value is changing that another composable is reading.