# How to observe livedata in Compose within coroutines

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit2, android-livedata

I am practicing compose along with layout based app since it is interoperable

I am facing issue in observing the livedata of my view model inside the compose screen using rememberCoroutineScope.

Consider this is my compose Screen:

VersionScreen.kt

```
package com.example.coroutinepractice.ui.composeUi.versionCompose

import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.colorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.coroutinepractice.R
import com.example.coroutinepractice.requests.VersionRequestItem
import com.example.coroutinepractice.responses.Comments
import com.example.coroutinepractice.theme.PracticeTheme
import com.example.coroutinepractice.viewModels.MyViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@Composable
fun VersionScreen() {
    var version by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val versionRequestItem = VersionRequestItem()
    val myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    var status = myViewModel.comments.observeAsState().value

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth(), color = colorResource(id = R.color.black)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text(text = version, color = colorResource(id = R.color.dark_yellow))
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    version =
                        callVersionApi(versionRequestItem, myViewModel, coroutineScope, status)
                },
                modifier = Modifier,
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(colorResource(id = R.color.dark_yellow))
            ) {
                Text(text = "Click on me", color = colorResource(id = R.color.black))
            }
        }
    }

}

fun callVersionApi(
    versionRequestItem: VersionRequestItem,
    myViewModel: MyViewModel,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    status: Comments?,
): String {
    var versionStatus: String = ""
    coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        versionRequestItem.Version_Name = "1"
        versionRequestItem.Version_Number = "1.0"
        versionRequestItem.Login = "GMM3671"
        myViewModel.getComments(versionRequestItem)
        val appVersion = status?.status
        if (appVersion != null) {
            versionStatus = appVersion
        }

    }
    return versionStatus
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun VersionScreenPreview() {
    PracticeTheme {
        VersionScreen()
    }
}
```

MyViewModel:

```
package com.example.coroutinepractice.viewModels

import androidx.databinding.ObservableField
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.coroutinepractice.data.repository.MyRepository
import com.example.coroutinepractice.requests.VersionRequestItem
import com.example.coroutinepractice.responses.Comments
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    private val myRepository = MyRepository()
    private val _comments = MutableLiveData<Comments>()
    val version = ObservableField<String>("")
    val comments: LiveData<Comments> = _comments

    suspend fun getComments(versionRequestItem: VersionRequestItem) =
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val data = myRepository.getAppVersion(versionRequestItem)
            if (data.body() != null && data.isSuccessful) {
                _comments.postValue(data.body())
            }
        }

}
```

When i am trying to observe comments liveData via status variable in compose screen, i am getting as null although my api sends me successful response. What i am doing wrong here?

This is the response i am getting in my logcat:

`2023-11-29 14:28:15.915 16057-16849 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.coroutinepractice        I  {"status":0}`

I want to display the value of status i.e 0 in my text box on click of button with text "Click on me".

I tried working with LaunchedEffect(Unit) and observe live data it is working fine, but i want to hit api on button click.

Using launched effect hits api as soon as i navigate to my Compose screen (VersionScreen). I want to hit api on button click.

**Edit: I just checked by hitting the button twice i can see the data as "0" printed on the text above button. That means for first time it comes null and then I hit api second time I can see the data. What could be the issue here?**

Comment: You must initialize the viewmodel directly in the constructor of the `VersionScreen`. Use the `viewmodel` api to do that like this,
`fun VersionScreen(myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel())`

Comment: @MeetPrajapati thanks for the suggestion, but it works the same way. I tried it, this does not solve my issue.

Comment: When user clicks the button you must receive the output in this 
`var status = myViewModel.comments.observeAsState().value` Are you getting this `status` `null`?

Comment: @MeetPrajapati yes

Comment: You can try one thing use `MutableState` instead, I think MutableLiveData is not triggering the recomposition.

Comment: Check this for viewmodel implementation : https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-unscramble/blob/viewmodel/app/src/main/java/com/example/unscramble/ui/GameViewModel.kt

Check this for it's usage : https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-unscramble/blob/viewmodel/app/src/main/java/com/example/unscramble/ui/GameScreen.kt

Comment: this answer might help you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68638606/13062000)